# Javascript import command

Tags: javascript, android, import, duktape

Does it matter where `require` is put within a file? This is using duktape to use js function in my android app.

For Example:

```
some javascript code
var calc = require('calculate')
```

Then call `calc.calculate`

I normally would declare calc first such as

```
var calc = require('calculate')
some javascript code
```

Does this make any difference in JS??

Comment: `require` !== `import` - You have confounded two completely different features. Please change all references from "import" to "require".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`require` is a function, you can call it anywhere within your JavaScript file.

It's typically used at the top of a file because it's useful to see the file's dependencies all in one place, but it's not necessary.

Note that `require` has **very** different semantics than JavaScript's own `import`, and `import()`, which will eventually replace `require`.